# How to generate a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a database about football(soccer) statistics. One of the tables is **matches** with rows such as:

- id
- match_date
- home_team
- away_team
- home_level
- away_level
- home_score
- away score

And another table is **goal**, with rows such as:

- id
- match_id
- goal_minute
- home_team
- away_team
- home_level
- away_level
- goal_team
- concede_team
- goal_type_id
- attack_type_id

And I want to select all of the goals when home_level is 3 **and** away_level is 1 **and** (away_score - home_score > 2).

How can I generate this query including 2 tables?

Comment: Hint:  you'll want to use a `JOIN`.

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo: https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Queries-Mere-Mortals-Hands/dp/0321992474/

Comment: Those look a lot like columns

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select  * 
from    matches m, 
        goal    g 
where   m.id = g.match_id 
and     g.home_level = 3 
and     g.away_level = 1 
and     m.away_score - m.home_score > 2
```

or

```
select  * 
from     matches m, 
         goal    g 
where    m.id = g.match_id 
and      g.home_level = 3 
and      g.away_level = 1 
and      (m.away_score - m.home_score) > 2
```

or

```
select     * 
from       matches m 
INNER_JOIN goal    g  ON  m.id = g.match_id 
                      and g.home_level = 3 
                      and g.away_level = 1 
                      and (m.away_score - m.home_score) > 2
```

Comment: Please do not recommend solutions using the implicit `JOIN` syntax that was deprecated **[over 25 years ago](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)**.  Some modern DBMS's don't even support this anymore.  As a rule of thumb, you should *never* have a `,` in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's working well. Could you also tell me how I can find any information about creating queries like this?

Comment: There's a nice site to teach you basic SQL command called [SQLBolt](https://sqlbolt.com/) .

Comment: Sure, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html The MySQL docs have a lot to teach about if you stop to read the scenarios, like said by Siyual, use JOIN syntax, it is pretty better for performance. But, implicity joins its better for understanding. Take a look at this too: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Could you check it as the answer? Thanks ;)

Comment: There is no difference in performance between the two join syntax styles. All mainstream RDBMS implementations optimize both styles the same. The older style is not actually deprecated. It's still in the SQL specification for backward compatibility, but of course you can't do outer joins and such unless you use the new syntax.